# KL (Kullback-Leibler divergence) definition

Tags: definition, convex-optimization

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/):

The book defines KL as below.
[image]

Why $-u_i + v_i$ term is there? Is this the original definition of KL-divergence and for probability distribution these terms are not there as they cancel out?

Comment: when $u_i$, $v_j$ are probability measures $\sum_nv_j=\sum_nu_j=1$ so the additional terms cancels. Thus, the expression indeed generalizes the concept of entropy (KL divergence) for probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite measures on $(X,\mathscr{F})$ and that $\nu\ll \mu$, and assume $\nu(X)>0$. Define

\begin{align}
H(\nu|\mu)&:=\int_X\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\,d\nu-\big(\mu(X)-\nu(X)\big)\\
&=\int_X\Big(\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}-1+\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\Big)\,d\mu
\end{align}
Notice that if $\mu(X)=\nu(X)$ the definition above yields back the definition of entropy (KL-divergence) for probability measures.

---

Here is a relation between to "more" general concept of KL-divergence and that for probability measures.

Consider the *normalized* measures $\overline{\mu}=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\mu$ and $\overline{\nu}=\frac{1}{\nu(X)}\nu$. Then
\begin{align}
0\leq H(\overline{\nu}|\overline{\mu})&=\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\left(\int_X\log\big(\frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}\big) \frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,d\mu+\int_X\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,d\mu\right)\\
&=\log\big(\frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}\big)+\frac{1}{\nu(X)}\int_X\log\big(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\big)\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,d\mu\\
&=\log\big(\frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}\big)+\frac{1}{\nu(X)}\Big(H(\nu|\mu)+\mu(X)-\nu(X)\Big)
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
H(\nu|\mu)&=\nu(X)\Big(H(\overline{\nu}|\overline{\mu})-\log(\mu(X)/\nu(X))\Big)-(\mu(X)-\nu(X))\\
&\geq-\nu(X)\Big(\log(\mu(X)/\nu(X))+\big(\frac{\mu(X)}{\nu(X)}-1\big)\Big)
\end{align}

If $\mu(X)\leq\nu(X)$, then $H(\nu|\mu)\geq0$ and if $\mu(X)>\nu(X)$, $H(\nu|\mu)<0$.